# Excel VBA , Excel files in a folder on sharepoint cannot be read

Tags: microsoft-excel, import, sharepoint, open

can anyone tell me what the problem is that the path cannot be found?
When I execute the script, an error message is always displayed at the same place (runtime error 76).

```
 Sub GetData ()
Dim oMe As Worksheet, iLine As Long, oFile As Object
Dim oFS As Object, wbQuelle As Workbook
Set oMe = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Const sDateiPfad As String = "https:\\xxxx.sharepoint.com\sites\001073\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\Anmeldungen\" 'Path is changed because of data protection
iZeile = 19
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set oFS = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each oDatei In oFS.GetFolder (sDateiPfad). Files
If InStrRev (oDatei.name, "xlsx") Then
 Set wbQuelle = Workbooks.Open (sDateiPfad & oDatei.name)
 With wbQuelle.ActiveSheet
oMe.Cells (iZeile, 2) = .Range ("B5")
oMe.Cells (iZeile, 3) = .Range ("B13")
oMe.Cells (iZeile, 4) = .Range ("B14")
oMe.Cells (iZeile, 5) = .Range ("B15")
oMe.Cells (iZeile, 6) = .Range ("B16")
oMe.Cells (iZeile, 7) = .Range ("B17")
oMe.Cells (iZeile, 8) = .Range ("B22")
oMe.Cells (iZeile, 9) = .Range ("B28")
oMe.Cells (iZeile, 10) = .Range ("B29")
oMe.Cells (iZeile, 11) = .Range ("B36")
oMe.Cells (iZeile, 12) = .Range ("B24")
oMe.Cells (iZeile, 13) = .Range ("G30")
oMe.Cells (iZeile, 14) = .Range ("H53")
oMe.Cells (iZeile, 15) = .Range ("B30")
oMe.Cells (iZeile, 16) = .Range ("B31")
oMe.Cells (iZeile, 17) = .Range ("G26")
oMe.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=oMe.Cells (iZeile, 29), Address:=sDateiPfad_
& wbQuelle.name, TextToDisplay:=wbQuelle.name
wbQuelle.Close False
iZeile = iZeile + 1
End With
End If
Next
Set oMe = Nothing: Set wbQuelle = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! "an error message is always displayed at the same place", what place, what line of code?

Comment: Yes, always in the same place.For Each oDatei In oFS.GetFolder (sDateiPfad).Files

Comment: See answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511625/runtime-error-76-path-not-found

Comment: So, you think I need to adjust the path (/?/)

Comment: I don't know since I don't have a file hosted online. But what is certain is the path is he problem as stated [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/path-not-found-error-76). So, you have to make sure that the macro can handle the path given. Test each answer given to that previous link to check if any of them work for you.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint (and OneDrive) path+filename cannot exceed 400 characters when using Excel. So if the real path+filename the macro uses is longer, nothing is served up, so to speak.

Several factors affect the file naming and path lengths, and you can, under circumstances, use as many as 32767 characters though you need to make a change to Windows for that (quite an easy one). It does not guarantee any particular program (Excel, SharePoint, etc.) can use the new `MAX_PATH` length fully, or at all. Same for Windows API32, used by most any program. The Windows Shell, which is called upon for many things also used to limit one. And even then, a program like Excel, expecting an environment limiting it to 260 characters (255 "real" and a few more "faux" bytes),  might have code that enforces that limit so even if it could actually use the longer limit if coded so, well, it isn't updated yet so...

The `\\?\` approach can be used for many things, but cannot overcome refusal by a program to consider the naming data sent using it. It might make something addressable, and offers other advantages to coders, but it can't make a program that is coded to not use a path+filename longer than "whatever length" start using longer ones. SharePoint is an example.

A couple other oddities apply as well.

But your particular situation PROBABLY (because the actual path is not revealed above) runs into SharePoint's brick wall of 400 characters and so it cannot use the naming data sent to it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I think you're right, the background path to SharePoint is too long. There's nothing I can do about that.